# Local domain names for moving development machine

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, development

I want to create a local kubernetes (minikube) and glusterfs setup on my laptop which will continue to work as I move location.

The problem with this is that some aspects of the setup require an ip address/resolvable domain name to be used. The minikube setup ignores my /etc/hosts and every location will provide a different IP address for my machine, so hard coding the IP address is annoying and time consuming as I have to tear down, edit, and then recreate the setup.

My first thought was to up a DNS server like BIND locally which would return the machine's IP address but I can't find anything on how to return the current machine's IP address.

Anyone have any ideas of a way to do this or some alternative setup that would provide the same functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the addresses used by your local host, or by clients on whatever LAN you are on?

Comment: Thanks for the response. They'll be used just by my laptop, it's only for local development.

Comment: I'd look into adding a static IP on the NIC (in addition to the DHCP assigned one), and run a DNS server and your dev infrastructure on it. that way the IP to the internet from any given LAN works automatically, and the statically assigned items like your database and webserver or whatever are always on the static.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That sounds like it should work. I can do that but if you'd like the credit for an answered question you could create a fully filled out answer on how to do that.

If you don't care then I can create an answer based on what you said when I found out the details and give credit to your comment as best I can.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Frank Thomas's hint I eventually found a rough way of doing this.

I hate BASH scripting and there might well be other issues with this so if anyone has a better way to do this by all means add a comment suggesting ways to make it better and I'll update it.

For ubuntu 16.04 I created a file named addip in /etc/network/if-up.d with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

ADDITIONAL_IPADDR="10.0.0.111/24"
PREFERRED_INTERFACE="wlp4s0"

# Description:      Add ip address to allow for local services on a machine that's
#                       assigned an ip address by dhcp over a wifi nic
if [ $IFACE != $PREFERRED_INTERFACE ] || [ $ADDRFAM != inet ]; then
    exit 0
fi

if [ -x /bin/ip ] ; then
    # ip already present?
    ip addr show | grep -q "$ADDITIONAL_IPADDR[[:space:]]" && exit 0
    /sbin/ip addr add $ADDITIONAL_IPADDR dev $PREFERRED_INTERFACE
fi
```

You're probably going to want to change the values of ADDITIONAL_IPADDR and PREFERRED_INTERFACE.

Then you can set up your preferred DNS server to return this IP address you set in ADDITIONAL_IPADDR for your setup.